# Subscribe ionic single event in different pages for multiple times

Tags: angular, events, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to publish a single event in one page and subscribe multiple times on different pages. Like this..

```
handleClick(){
  this.events1.publish('my-message', ' Hello from page1!');
}


export class Page1Page {
  constructor(public events1: Events) {
     events1.subscribe('my-message', (data) =>{
       console.log(data); //  Hello from page1!
     });
  }
}


export class Page2Page {
  constructor(public events1: Events) {
     events1.subscribe('my-message', (data) =>{
       console.log(data); //  Hello from page2!
     });
  }
}
```

Is it a good practice? Or this code gives error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to trigger with this event?  In my experience the subscribing of these events would happen outside of a page (e.g. in a service).  Then that service could navigate to a page (or do whatever you need).

Comment: @BRass I want to publish events from the service (this events will be publish on network changes like 'offline' and 'online')... so i want to listen this events on currently active pages...

Comment: Perhaps this helps? http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#multicasted-observables

Answer (score 1):

OK.  Here's my take on this.  I see 3 pieces of the puzzle:

1) You need something to tell you about the network connectivity.  I would start with the Network `cordova-plugin-network-information` plugin that is wrapped by [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/).

2) You should create an Angular service/provider that works with this network plugin to be aware of network changes.  It can then expose this data for pages to use (and trigger events as needed).  Also be aware that the app will likely only here of updates when the app is up, so you may want to get the current status on `ready` (startup) and `resume` (open from background).  See the [Ionic Platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/) for those hooks.

3) Your pages can then leverage that service/provider from #2 to display the current online status (and possibly watch for changes if your UI needs to alert of change and not just display the current status).